# e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

The app in question is basically a DOM inspector tool similar to the one available in Chrome Dev Tools made using plain JS. Basically when the user clicks on an element attributes such as class names, xpaths and texts should be available to the user. I have run into a problem which is: When a user clicks on an element such as a link or a button, the browser navigates to the intended page. I have tried to prevent this problem using the following piece of code:

```
var target = getSelectedElementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY); // target has the element the user wants to inspect
if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a" || target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "button"){
        e.stopPropagation(); // e is the event
        e.preventDefault();
 }
```

The intention of the code is to get the element the user clicks on, check if it is an anchor tag or a button and if so, stop the event from progressing further. However, it does not work as expected as, on mouse click, it still navigates to the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Please note that I cannot use jQuery in this particular instance. Thanks

EDIT2: Probably should have mentioned this earlier but I forgot.
I have actually tried `return false` as well. Using return false achieves the required functionality but the only problem being, once the user leaves the "Inspect mode" that link is no longer clickable and that is not desirable behavior.

Basically what I want is that when the user enters the "Inspect mode" for all links to be unclickable. And these links should be clickable once "Inspect mode" is removed. Rather than disable all links on the page, I thought of disabling the one the user clicked on.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? There isn't enough context for the code in the question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for replying :) Sure I can, but I am not sure what other information is needed...? Could you maybe tell me which part you find is unclear and I could try to explain further? Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried to 'return false;' ?

Comment: @PoulBak thanks for the reply :) And yeah could you please check the latest update to my question to see the outcome of `return false`. Thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe the question is a little bit more clearer now?

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`? Although a better way might be to just have an overlay that takes the clicks instead of the elements themselves so you don't have to add more events to them.

Comment: @user538578964 — A [mcve] lets us see exactly what you are doing, test it, and try out changes. Creating one also acts an an exercise in narrowing down the problem, which can lead to you finding a solution yourself.

Comment: @somethinghere `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` has no change in the result, sadly. Actually, having a `div` overlay the entire screen to catch the clicks was the first implementation although I had to change it because, when I put a div over the screen, it causes some UI elements (such as menu which are only visible on hover) to disappear :(

Comment: @Quentin I have edited my question after the original posting. Is it sufficient now? Thanks

Comment: @user538578964 — You have not edited you question since 5 minutes before I made my last comment.

Comment: The only way to accomplish this without an overlay is to bind any element _before_ any other event listeners are added. You could potentially do this with a `MutationObserver`, but even then it might be delayed. The reason dev tools work so well on browsers is that they can mash themselves in front of amnything, which you can't do in the page itself...

Comment: @somethinghere I've been hacking away at this for the past 3 hours and still havent made much progress. I have decided it would be best to go for the overlay option you suggested and the one that was implemented earlier. The problem I was having with it was that when the overlay appears, it removes any UI elements which are available on hover. Would you happen to know why? Thanks

Comment: Because you arent hovering on them, you are hovering on the overlay. Perhaps best to add a style rule with overwriting any invisible bits?

Comment: @somethinghere These are the style attributes of my overlay `style="height: 2775px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: visible; display: block; z-index: 2147483550; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1423px;"` Do you see anything wrong with it? Thanks

Comment: It doesnt matter - your cursor will never hover over anything below it - thats the point. You can see al events and catch them before they reach the object. That also means hovering is not an option.

Comment: @somethinghere I see.. So how would you recommend to fix it? Or is it virtually impossible to accomplish what is needed? I didnt totally understand your suggestion about the "style rule with overwriting any invisible bits"

Comment: Well, if hover makes something go to opacity 1, simply make it opacity 1. I dont know if you noticed, but when targeting elements in dev tools hover effects get ignored as well unless they are active when targeting begins. That because deciding what to do - selecting or hovering - is a subjective decision. You cant target what isnt there.

Comment: @somethinghere I think I was unclear in my intention. Because thats the exact behaviour I want. Ex: The user can hover over a menu and then go to Inspect Mode using a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + C) and then inspect the menu. What happens in the current implementation is that, when the user hovers over the menu and goes into Inspect Mode, the hovered upon menu disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply wrap your code in a check for `'inspectMode'`. `'inspectMode'` should be a boolean var.

Add the foloowing code to your eventhandler:

```
if (inspectMode)
{
    var target = getSelectedElementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a" || target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "button")    
    {
        e.stopPropagation(); // e is the event
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work either as the code snippet I put in the question is reached only if its in inspector mode. So surrounding it with an `if` block would have little to no difference :(

Comment: How do you attach your eventhandler, do you use 'addEventListener()' or do you assign your eventlistener directly?

Comment: I attach an eventlistener to the body of the webpage using `object.addEventListener(name, handler, useCapture);` where `name` can be `mousedown` or `mousedown`